# key value style javascript array`s length keeps being 0

Tags: javascript

I fill my key value array like this:

```
/**
 * Callback: Gets invoked by the server when the data returns
 * 
 * @param {Object} aObject
 */
function retrieveStringsFromServerCallback(aObject){

   for(var i = 0;i < aObject['xml'].strings.appStringsList.length;i++){
      var tKey = aObject['xml'].strings.appStringsList[i]["@key"];      
      var tValue = aObject['xml'].strings.appStringsList[i]['$'];
      configManager.addStringElement(tKey,tValue);

   }
}
```

Here is the setter of my object

```
/**
 * @param {string} aKey
 * @param {string} aValue
 */
this.addStringElement = function(aKey, aValue){
    self.iStringMap[aKey] = aValue;
    console.log("LENGTH: "+self.iStringMap.length);
}
```

I add about 300 key value pairs, according to google chrome inspector, the `iStringMap` is filled correctly. However the length of the array seems still to be 0. There must be something wrong. Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the count of object keys using:

```
Object.keys(obj).length
```

`Object.keys()` returns an array of keys of an object passed as a first parameter. And after that you're accessing the `.length` of that array.

Comment: ok nice, it prints the correct length. So the array.length operator returns 0 because the array is filled with objects?

Comment: @dan: no, it returns `0` because it's not an array, it's an object. Array and object are different containers in JS